# jQuery make .change and .click event for different element to call same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I googled but most of them is to bind different event for SAME element.

For

```
$('#a').change(function() {
     /bla
     /bla
});

$('#b').click(function(){
     /bla
     /bla
});
```

I want something like this

```
$('#a').change OR ('#b').click(function(){
     /bla
     /bla
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var func = function(){
     /bla
     /bla
};

$('#a').change(func);
$('#b').click(func);
```

Comment: such a simple solution and i was looking for some binding event _*_

Answer (score 3):

Why not just put the code you want to reuse in a function and, well, reuse it?

```
function doSomething() {
  // bla
}
```

Then...

```
$('#a').change(function() {
     doSomething();
});

$('#b').click(function(){
     doSomething();
});
```

Comment: such a simple solution and i was looking for some binding event _*_